# PHP regex and repeated patterns

Tags: php, regex

I'd like to match these strings using preg_match, basicaly only repeated patterns of digits and a comma (optional), no letters

```
123
123,
123,456
123,456,
123,456,789
123,456,789,
etc...
```

but not

```
abc
123,abc
123,abc,456
abc,123,456
```

thanks

Comment: `[0-9]+(?:,[0-9]*)*`? Demo: https://regex101.com/r/iR3bC3/1

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "repeated pattern"? Show us other possible patterns.

Comment: the repeated pattern is \n+\,*. when there's a letter I need preg_match to return false

Comment: @stachu i think so to validate string `^([0-9]+)(?:,([0-9]+))*$`

Comment: @splash58 this one won't work for "123,456,"

Comment: @user3174311: is `123,4567` correct?

Comment: `^([0-9]+)(?:,([0-9]+))*,?$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put comma and the pattern to match one or more digits inside  a non-capturing group and then make it to repaet zero or more times. And also don't forget to add an optional comma at the last.

```
^[0-9]+(?:,[0-9]+)*,?$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/dG5pA9/5)